Find matching variable in df2 based on multiple variables of df1 and grouped by categorical variable of df1
Example:
# Data frame 1
df1 <- data.frame(
  team = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
  value1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  value2 = c(50, 46, 38, 87, 90, 25)
)

# Data frame 2 (without team variable)
df2 <- data.frame(
  value = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 6),
  value2 = c(50, 38, 50, 76, 18, 87, 46, 90, 88, 25),
  team_captain = c("Tom", "Tom", "Joe", "Joe","Zion", "Parker", "Parker","Alex", "Mike", "Alex")
)

# Goal
df_result <- data.frame(
  team = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
  value1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  value2 = c(50, 46, 38, 87, 90, 25),
  team_captain = c("Tom", "Parker", "Tom", "Parker","Alex", "Alex")
)

How to combine df1 and df2 so you get df_result?
In reality the data frames are much larger and there are more values so it's no options to just make a mapping table which contains the team and team_captain.
Tried joining but it looks like I first need to group_by before joining which is not working.
